# C# / Linq-to-sql - Lock datacontext.Table on insertonsubmit

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm currently creating a method on my data access class that is going to insert an entity object to the database and I was expecting to get the latest inserted ID afterwards... and I've already done that but then I was wondering what would happend if the method somehow gets invoked twice at the same time, would it return the wrong ID?

So as a work around to that I decided to Lock the table on my datacontext:

```
lock(dataContext.Persons)
{
    InsertOnSubmit(person);
    dataContext.SubmitChanges();
}
```

but I do feel like this is inappropriate... I mean, the table isnt big and it wont take long to the datacontext to submit changes... So my question is, what kind of trouble would I run into by locking it like that?

PS: Let me know if my question was not clear enough and I'll edit it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to lock your table.

LINQ-to-SQL will automatically populate your `ID` field with the identity from the database upon your call to `.SubmitChanges()` when you insert your `person`.

The caveat is that both your database and L2S entity must define your `ID` field as an **identity**.  On your `Person` entity, you should have that field defined as the primary key, `IsDbGenerated=true`, `UpdateCheck=never`, and have the correct database type.

Once you submit, you should be able to simply retrieve the `ID` from your `Person` entity:

```
dataContext.Persons.InsertOnSubmit(person);
dataContext.SubmitChanges();
var id = person.ID; // now has the database generated identity.
```

Comment: Ok thank you.. but do you know what could possibly go wrong if I had this lock?

Comment: @BSarkis: Not sure what you mean by _go wrong_. You aren't preventing anyone from touching that table outside of this lock, you're only protecting this single block of code from concurrency.

Comment: I see, that is the kind of answer I was looking for, thank you once again.

Comment: @Marc do you have any links to support your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if this is part of your concerns, but if you use TransactionScope you can pass in a TransactionOption that will deal with multiple transactions.

Check out [TransactionOption.Isolationlevel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.isolationlevel%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Not really sure if it would help in this scenario but I appreciate your attempt, I'll check it out.